# Is there is any changes in mimeType, exportLinks or downloadURL for the documents that are created or edited in GoogleDocs

Tags: google-drive-api

In my applciation, i used to convert the googleDocs edited documents to .pdf format. But, recently i am facing issue in converting it. Is there is any changes happended in API level ? i am using google-api-services-drive.jar -version v2-rev1-1.7.2-beta.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Please include a snippet of your code and the details of any errors you are seeing.

Comment: I see that you're using v2 of Drive. You can see all the changes that have happened since v3 came along in the [Migrate to Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration) guide. For example, the exportLinks field has been removed from files. To export Google Documents, use the files.export method instead.